# Valid type notation for dict and list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Is it correct, according to the PEP specification, to use `[str]` as the type notation for a list of strings? I thought that only `list[str]` (or in older versions `typing.List[str]`) was correct.

Because if we look at `{str}` for a dictionary, it's ambiguous if it means `dict[str, Any]`, `dict[Any, str]`, `dict[str, str]` or `set[str]`.

I have seen it being used in some code on GitHub, and now I'm wondering.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: You can use any syntactically valid expression as a type annotation, whether `[str]` would _work_ in any meaningful sense depends on whether your tooling supports it (e.g. MyPy [gives](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=552d02305063b040b31ba8bbaf21143f) `Bracketed expression "[...]" is not valid as a type`) with the same meaning you intend.

Comment: HomeAssistant for [str] for example

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, thanks. I guess that it's a question of convention, but mostly something one should rather not do, as mypy, one of the popularst tools, does not support it, becaue it can be amiguous.

Comment: @hendrik I don't believe there is a convention, other than the standard `list[str]`. I think `[str]` is always a list of types and _not a type hint_. As jon points out, it's valid Python, but it's not a valid type hint. I suspect codebases that do include it don't actually use a static type checker